# Subcategory Thumbnails are taking the Parent category thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

this is my first time posting here so I apologize if it doesn't fit standards.

As the name suggests, all of my subcategory thumbnails are taking the parent category thumbnail. I have about 30 subcategories displaying the same image in the thumbnail, even though I gave them each different thumbnails in "Categories" for WooCommerce.

I have been stuck on this for some time now, any help would be appreciated.

Here is the link: https://executiveminingservices.com/product-category/ground-engagement-tools/

Comment: External links are sure to expire, making any question that relies on them less useful. Try to put all the details you need into the body of the question. Also, you should probably show some code that describes the exact problem you are seeing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Questions should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help!